# Finding a point in the intersection of two polygons

Tags: collision-detection, computational-geometry

For two convex polygons I need to find a point inside their intersection. The edges and vertices of the intersection do not count. I don't have a requirement of where the point needs to be relative to the edges of the intersection, but preferably somewhere in the middle.

For collision detection I use SAP. If it's possible to incorporate the computation into SAP it'd be good since I need high speed of execution. Polygons have just a several vertices each, the shapes are very simple.

Comment: Please: show some effort; phrase as a question.

Comment: I thought the question is clear: what's the algorithm to find a point inside intersection of two convex polygons?

Comment: Seems like this http://www.codezealot.org/archives/394 might be the answer. Any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

A [Sweep Line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) approach can be used to do what you want - and sufficiently fast.

At first sort vertices of both polygons by their x-coordinate, then sweep vertical line from left to right until you find two intersecting segments - one from the first polygon, and second one from the second polygon. Then choose any internal point from the intersection of these segments and stop.